# Swift: how to colorize transparency background of an uiimage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to apply an "under circle mask" for a png image with transparency.

I tried:

```
var image = UIImage(named: "logo")!
image = image.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
self.imageViewLogo.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.imageViewLogo.image = image
```

If my logo is a transparent image with a cat black inside, this code produce the same image but with a red cat.

My purpose is to obtain the black cat with the red background color.

How can I achieve this without lack of performance?

[image]

Comment: self.imageViewLogo.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

Answer (score 1):

Using this...

```
image = image.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
```

Will use the non-transparent parts of the image as a template for how much of the tint color to apply.

What you want to do is just use the standard image and set the background color of the image view.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "logo")!
imageViewLogo.image = image
imageViewLogo.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

For rounded corners of the view so that it is in a circle you can add the following...

```
imageViewLogo.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame) * 0.5
imageViewLogo.clipsToBounds = true
```

That will round the corners with a radius of half the height and then clip the edges to the rounded corners.

Comment: @Velthune What do you mean? Can you show some images with examples of what you want. It's very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. If you don't ask the full question how can you expect a proper answer. Where in your question does it mention circles with borders? You said there is a cat and you want it to have a red background.

Comment: +1.. I already arrive to this "solution", but circle that I obtain have "jagged" border.. and without shadow as in my intention

Comment: @Velthune where in your question does it say that you have already tried this but it didn't work? Where did you mention shadows? Please, could you start again with your question. I suggest deleting everything (except the image) and explaining everything you have tried. And exactly what you wanted. Until then, best of luck. I'm not trying again because I don't know what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set background color of an image view

```
imageView.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

If you want to just use your image (image is black), you don't even need `tintColor` for image view and just set rendering mode of image to `.AlwaysOriginal`